# Are there organized educational WWII trips to Ukraine

Tags: tours, ukraine, world-war-ii

I am looking for professionally organized educational trips in the Ukraine.

A trip around Sevastopol/Crimea on the topic of WWII would be of special interest to me.

Does anyone know a company offering anything like that?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  There are many with varying degrees of depth.  Searching for "WW II tours Crimea" or "Great Patriotic War tours Crimea" will give you a significant list.  If you're able to read Russian or Ukrainian it may become even longer.  Given this please review the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) because your question in its current form falls under not constructive category and will likely be close.  You should look at editing the question narrowing the criteria down.

Comment: At first I thought it might be ok, but it's fairly broad. Is there a specific aspect of WW2 you'd like to see? Mines / war memorials / gum emplacements / factories etc?

Comment: Don't know about organized tours, but there are PLENTY of information about all kinds of military actions in that area on geocaching sites. Try russian geocahe site http://www.geocaching.su/?pn=19_eng. In case of geocache you get history, location and entertainment all in one box.